# How do I add post information to script tags with Blogger syntax?

Tags: blogger

My goal is to create a blogger widget that adds the following JS to every post page (just blog posts, not pages):

```
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    post_info = { 
        title: 'My Blog Post',                                              
        labels: 'this, that',                                              
        pub: '2011-07-05 18:15:52',
        url: 'http://foo.blogger.com/2011/07/my-blog-post.html'
    };
   </script>
```

I was thinking I would be able to do that with the following code:

```
<b:includable id='post' var='post'>
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    post_info = {
      <b:if cond='data:post.title'>
        title: &quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;,
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:post.postLabelsLabel'>
        labels: &quot;<data:post.postLabelsLabel/>&quot;,
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:post.timestampLabel'>
        pub: &quot;<data:post.timestampLabel/>&quot;,
      </b:if>
      <b:if cond='data:post.url'>
        url: &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;
      </b:if>
    };
  </script>
</b:if>
</b:includable>
```

Not only am I not sure where to put the code (cause I have gotten some weird errors about not placing things in a prolog), but when I don't get those errors, I get no such thing as post in 'blog' dictionary errors.

I haven't been able to find the documentation that covers adding things like this or whether or not I need to be using expr or macros or where this would need to go on the page (what container etc).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: You can edit the templates to include extra code.  That would probably be the place to start looking.

Comment: I have been doing that for the last 2 days and haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using some inexistent properties of **posts**: [Here is a full list of available properties](http://www.google.com/support/blogger/bin/answer.py?answer=47270&hl=en#posts)

And this is how JavaScript should look like:

```
<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            post_info = {
                title: &quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;,
                labels: [
                    <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                        &quot;<data:label.name/>&quot;
                        <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,</b:if>
                    </b:loop>
                ],
                pub: &quot;<data:post.timestamp/>&quot;,
                url: &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;
            };
        </script>
    </b:if>
</b:loop>
```

The easiest way is to put the above code in **b:includable** with `id='main'` which is in **b:widget** with `type='Blog'`.

Some third party tutorials that I used to learn something about blogger templates:

- http://templateofdoom.synthful.org/Home
- http://thoughtsomething.blogspot.com/2009/01/understanding-blogger-template-1.html

Comment: I am still getting the error when I even try just one of those (like labels):  `labels: 'TEMPLATE ERROR: No dictionary named: 'post' in: ['blog']'`.  When I try adding the includable post line like in the question, the whole section disappears.

Comment: @Eric I have updated my answer. Possibly the includable you used was not at the right place.

Comment: Same result. As soon as I add the `<b:loop values='data:posts' var='post'>` line, then the entire code block disappears.  I even moved it into the `id=main` **b:includable**.  When I remove the `<b:loop ...>`, then I just get blanks.

Comment: @Eric Is this **b:includable** in **b:widget** with `type='Blog'`?

Comment: @Eric Haven't you solved the problem yet? I think the best way would be to share your template, so that we could look in to it.

Comment: I still haven't solved anything.  Here is a link to a gist my [template](https://gist.github.com/1136988). It is roughly a stock template but everything in title, pub, url, and labels consistently comes up blank.

Comment: @Eric Hmm... For me everything works using instructions provided in my answer: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/170484/blogger-template.zip

Comment: I copied and pasted the code in the zipfile into the 'Design => Edit HTML' section of the admin portal.  This time the 'script' tags aren't  even coming up in the source of the page. I must be missing something.

Comment: @Eric You wanted this code to be visible on blog posts only. So you need to look into the source code of particular blog post, not the main page. Note: before pasting this code in my opinion you need to check `Expand Widget Templates` checkbox.

Comment: @Eric You can also look into the source code of this page: http://entellect.blogspot.com/2011/07/test-post.html :)

Comment: I have been checking on a blog post and the _Expand Widget Templates_ checkbox is always checked.  The <script> tags aren't coming up on posts or the main page or labels right now.

Comment: @Karolis let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2335/discussion-between-eric-lubow-and-karolis)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        post_info = {
            title: &quot;<data:post.title/>&quot;,
            labels: [
                <b:loop values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
                    &quot;<data:label.name/>&quot;
                    <b:if cond='data:label.isLast != &quot;true&quot;'>,</b:if>
                </b:loop>
            ],
            pub: &quot;<data:post.timestamp/>&quot;,
            url: &quot;<data:post.url/>&quot;
        };
    </script>
```